# My destenation folder is empty when running yarn build:css inside docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-7

Here is my Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ruby:3.0.3
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs npm yarn postgresql-client
RUN curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
RUN rails assets:precompile
COPY . /myapp
RUN npm install -g yarn -y
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build:css
RUN rails webpacker:install
RUN rails webpacker:clobber
RUN rails webpacker:compile

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000
# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And on my package.json I have the following

```
"scripts": {
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
```

}

When I run `docker-compose build` works fine but the command `RUN yarn build:css` has no efect, the `builds` folder is empty.

Comment: How are you verifying this?  How are you running the image you build?

Comment: I am checking the files in the file system.

Comment: In the host filesystem?  That's normal; everything that happens in a Dockerfile happens within the context of the Docker image build system, and it's harder to see what's happening there.  The results of a `docker build` won't appear in the original source directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into an issue similar to this and the source of the problem was in fact npm and yarn.

I was able to get my application up and running in a docker container.

A properly configured application using `cssbundling-rails` should not need to run the command

`"scripts": { "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules" },`

to get the application to generate the `build/application.css`

### npm known issue

Check your npm version, there is [an issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43338) if you are not using npm 7.1+ that basically prevents yarn from setting things up correctly.

Run `npm -v` and if necessary, upgrade npm with `npm install -g npm@latest`

If you had to upgrade npm, you will then need to close out your terminal and launch a new one, verify that the npm version is greater than 7.1.

After upgrading, re run `rails css:install:bootstrap`

And everything should be configured correctly.

### Bundle Watcher

From the [documentation for cssbundling-rails](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails)
"You develop using this approach by running the bundler in watch mode in a terminal with `yarn build:css --watch` (and your Rails server in another, if you're not using something like [puma-dev](https://github.com/puma/puma-dev)). You can also use `./bin/dev`, which will start both the Rails server and the CSS build watcher (along with a JS build watcher, if you're also using `jsbundling-rails`)."

So, you can either run `yarn build:css --watch` from a separate terminal in your rails application or just use the `./bin/dev` but either way should resolve the issue you are experience.